# Multiple bibliographies in HTML, using keywords - is it possible?

Tags: html, r-markdown, bibliography

I am making a CV in R Markdown, and I have the following code that uses Latex to render multiple bibliography sections based on the `keywords={}` argument in the bibtex reference:

```
---
header-includes: \usepackage{tikz,xcolor,listings,CormorantGaramond,fontawesome,academicons,mfirstuc,fancyhdr,multicol}
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    citation_package: biblatex
    toc: no
    latex_engine: lualatex
biblio-style: apa
bibliography: MyPubs.bib
---

\underline{\textbf{Publications}}

\begin{refsection}
\setlength\bibitemsep{\baselineskip}
\nocite{*}
\noindent\printbibliography[heading=none, keyword = mypapers]
\end{refsection}

\underline{\textbf{Presentations}}

\begin{refsection}
\setlength\bibitemsep{\baselineskip}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=none, keyword = mypresentations]
\end{refsection}
```

The resulting behavior is as follows: R Markdown renders a PDF with two separate bibliographies: a Publication section that pulls references from my .bib file that have the mypublications keywords, and a separate section for Presentations (from refs with mypresentations keywords).

The output is PDF, but **how do you duplicate this behavior in HTML?**

I'm having a hard time finding info on this; is it possible? Thank you in advance for any guidance you can provide.